# Does anyone understand this sequence and how to apply it to 4 returns

Tags: python, pygame

The code creates and calls 3 buttons each with 3 colours - when the button is left alone, hovered over and then when pressed. When pressed a red larger rectangle is drawn with another regular rectangle on top to give the appearance of a red boarder

The boarder can only be given to one of the three buttons at a time (clicking on a new button when one has been previously clicked gives the new one a boarder and removes it from the old)

This all works as well as the functions

I don't understand how this pattern works and I need to know to apply it to 4 returns:
Changing the order of the returns drastically changes the results
Any help would be appreciated

```
is1Pressed, is2Pressed, is3Pressed = ColourButton("Orange",MidX-180+260,MidY,100,50,is1Pressed,is2Pressed,is3Pressed,CYAN,LIME,RED,"ORANGE1")
is2Pressed, is1Pressed, is3Pressed = ColourButton("Red",MidX-180,MidY,100,50,is2Pressed,is1Pressed,is3Pressed,CYAN,LIME,RED,"RED1")
is3Pressed, is1Pressed, is2Pressed = ColourButton("Green",MidX-180+130,MidY,100,50,is3Pressed,is1Pressed,is2Pressed,CYAN,LIME,RED,"GREEN1")
```

This is found at the start of a function calling the function further below:

```
is1Pressed = False  # Red 
is2Pressed = False  # Orange
is3Pressed = False  # Green
```

This is the function:

```
def ColourButton(msg,x,y,width,height,b1Pressed,b2Pressed,b3Pressed,inactive,active,pressed,action=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    # Allows me to take any clicking on the mouse as an input
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    #If the mouse is in the given area then a new rectangle with a different colour will be displayed
    if x+width > mouse[0] > x and y+height > mouse[1] > y:
        if not b1Pressed:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, active,(x,y,width,height))
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, pressed,(x-5,y-5,width+10,height+10))
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, inactive,(x,y,width,height))
        # If the left button on the mouse is pressed
        if click[0] == 1:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, pressed,(x-5,y-5,width+10,height+10))
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, inactive,(x,y,width,height))
            b1Pressed = True
            if b2Pressed or b3Pressed:
                b2Pressed = False
                b3Pressed = False
            
            # 10th of a second delay which makes the buttons feel more like they're being pressed
            time.sleep(0.1)
            # A list of actions that can be used when creating the button
            if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
                if action == "ORANGE1":
                    P1.image.fill(ORANGE)
                elif action == "RED1":
                    P1.image.fill(RED)
                elif action == "GREEN1":
                    P1.image.fill(GREEN)

    else:
        if not b1Pressed:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, inactive,(x,y,width,height))
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, pressed,(x-5,y-5,width+10,height+10))
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, inactive,(x,y,width,height))
    # The text on the button
    smallText = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf",20)
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, smallText)
    textRect.center = ( (x+(width/2)), (y+(height/2)) )
    screen.blit(textSurf, textRect)
    return b1Pressed, b2Pressed, b3Pressed
```

Answer (score 0):

well, when you call the buttons, the parameter `b1Pressed` is `is1Pressed`, for the second button, its `is2Pressed` and the third button, `is3Pressed`, this means that in the function, b1Pressed is always the current button, the only code you need to change is to add a 4th paramter, `b4Pressed` and set it to False when you set the other 2 to False

```py
def ColourButton(msg,x,y,width,height,b1Pressed,b2Pressed,b3Pressed,b4Pressed ,inactive,active,pressed,action=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    # Allows me to take any clicking on the mouse as an input
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    #If the mouse is in the given area then a new rectangle with a different colour will be displayed
    if x+width > mouse[0] > x and y+height > mouse[1] > y:
        if not b1Pressed:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, active,(x,y,width,height))
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, pressed,(x-5,y-5,width+10,height+10))
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, inactive,(x,y,width,height))
        # If the left button on the mouse is pressed
        if click[0] == 1:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, pressed,(x-5,y-5,width+10,height+10))
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, inactive,(x,y,width,height))
            b1Pressed = True
            if b2Pressed or b3Pressed or b4Pressed:
                b2Pressed = False
                b3Pressed = False
                b4Pressed = False
            
            # 10th of a second delay which makes the buttons feel more like they're being pressed
            time.sleep(0.1)
            # A list of actions that can be used when creating the button
            if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
                if action == "ORANGE1":
                    P1.image.fill(ORANGE)
                elif action == "RED1":
                    P1.image.fill(RED)
                elif action == "GREEN1":
                    P1.image.fill(GREEN)

    else:
        if not b1Pressed:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, inactive,(x,y,width,height))
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, pressed,(x-5,y-5,width+10,height+10))
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, inactive,(x,y,width,height))
    # The text on the button
    smallText = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf",20)
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, smallText)
    textRect.center = ( (x+(width/2)), (y+(height/2)) )
    screen.blit(textSurf, textRect)
    return b1Pressed, b2Pressed, b3Pressed, b4Pressed
```

```py
is1Pressed = False  # Red 
is2Pressed = False  # Orange
is3Pressed = False  # Green
is3Pressed = False

is1Pressed, is2Pressed, is3Pressed, is4Pressed = ColourButton("Orange",MidX-180+260,MidY,100,50,is1Pressed,is2Pressed,is3Pressed,CYAN,LIME,RED,"ORANGE1")
is2Pressed, is1Pressed, is3Pressed, is4Pressed = ColourButton("Red",MidX-180,MidY,100,50,is2Pressed,is1Pressed,is3Pressed,is4Pressed,CYAN,LIME,RED,"RED1")
is3Pressed, is1Pressed, is2Pressed, is4Pressed = ColourButton("Green",MidX-180+130,MidY,100,50,is3Pressed,is1Pressed,is2Pressed,is4Pressed,CYAN,LIME,RED,"GREEN1")
is3Pressed, is1Pressed, is2Pressed, is4Pressed = ColourButton("Green",MidX-180+390,MidY,100,50,is4Pressed,is1Pressed,is2Pressed,is3Pressed,CYAN,LIME,RED,"GREEN1")
```

Note. untested